# Is “The two types of beaver are.” grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Sentence: The two types of beaver are.

I was asked in class if this was a fragment. It clearly sounds like one, but it caused me to wonder if the word are can be used intransitively. I know it is technically a form of be, and the infinitive of be can mean to exist. So could the sentence be saying that two types of beaver exist?

Comment: You might quibble with the definite article "The" at the beginning of the sentence, given that, although two species of the genus _Castor_ (the North American beaver and the Eurasian beaver) are extant today ([according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beaver)), there have been other members of the family _Castoridae_ in the past, including two species of [giant beavers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castoroides) of Pleistocene North America, which most certainly are not (anymore). Hence it would be truer to say "Two types of beaver are, but at least two others are not."

Comment: It’s not that they exist, but that they are “*whatever was being discussed*”:  Here we see a group of animals including a fox, an elephant two types of beaver, and a bird. Question: Which of these animals are capable of building a dam?  Answer: The two types of beaver are.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, *be*, in any of its conjugations, can mean *exist*. To quote the OED:

> **be (verb) I.1.a**: to have place in the objective universe or realm of fact, to exist; (spec. of God, etc.) to exist independently of other beings. Also: to exist in life, to live.

However, your sentence sounds unnatural to me. At least in my experience, the use of *be* as above often connotes a degree of solemnity. Consider the examples given in the OED:

> The great beasts came first, strange forms that *were* when the world was new. (E. Nesbit)
>
> To *be*, or not to *be*, that is the question. (Shakespeare)
>
> God *is*, nay alone *is*. (Thomas Carlyle)

These examples all deal with remarkable topics: dragons, human existence, and God! For a more down-to-earth topic, like types of beavers, I would instead use the following.

> *There are* two types of beavers.